# aRb iff a-b is rational, is an equivalence relation on R?

Tags: proof-verification, equivalence-relations

This one may be obvious, but I could not find a solution to verify my proof.

Question: Is the following an equivalence relation on R?
$aRb\space$  iff$\space (a-b)\in Q$

My Solution:
Reflexive: $\forall a\in 
\mathbb{R},\space $$aRa \space[(a-a)\in Q]$
$a-a=0$ and $0\in Q$

Symmetric: $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R},\space aRb \rightarrow bRa\space[(a-b)\in Q \rightarrow (b-a)\in Q]$
Let $a-b = c$, where $c\in Q$, then $b-a=-c$. Well if $c\in Q$, then $(-c)\in Q$ as well.
So $(b-a)\in Q$ as well.

Transitive: $\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{R},\space aRb\wedge bRc\rightarrow aRc\space[((a-b)\in Q) \wedge ((b-c)\in Q)\rightarrow (a-c)\in Q]$
Let $a-b=d$, where $d\in Q$ and also let $b-c=e$, where $e\in Q$.
Consider $d+e$. Since rational numbers are closed under addition, then $(d+e)\in Q$
Which implies that $[(a-b)+(b-c)]\in Q \rightarrow (a-c)\in Q$

Since the relation is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, then the relation is an equivalence relation.

Comment: What are we supposed to do, check your answers?

Comment: Your "reflexive" part is wrong. Check the definition of "reflexive".

Comment: Reflexive means that $aRa$ is true.

Comment: Your "transitive" part has a typo. It should be $bRc$ instead of $bRa$. This mistake is then carried over to your subsequent steps.

Comment: Thank you all! Careless mistakes on my part.

Comment: Even after the edit, your reflexive part has typos / misconceptions.  Reflexive: $a\in \Bbb R\implies a\mathcal{R}a$.  There shouldn't be any mention of $b$ at all.  Further, your transitive section has a typo in it still  $[(a-b)\in\Bbb Q\wedge (b-\color{red}{c})\in\Bbb Q)\implies \dots)$

Comment: Please, James, see @JMoravitz 's comment immediately above.

Comment: Have you tried using digit sequences instead? It may be instructive.

Comment: Did I address all of my issues? I could not find the real numbers', "R" from mathjax. So, I just used another "R" to differentiate between the real numbers, and the relation.

Comment: `\Bbb R` or `\mathbb{R}` both produce $\Bbb R$.  The `\mathbb{R}` should also be default loaded into $\LaTeX$ or at least is in one of the standard packages that everyone should call in every situation.  Looking it over once more, yes, that appears to fix all of the issues.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously $a-b$ is rational iff $b-a$ is rational. All we need to show that the equivalence class of $a$ is well defined (and thus we have an equivalence relation) is that if $b-c$ is rational then $a-c$ is rational (given $a-b$ is rational). But $a-c=a-b+(b-c)$ is rational by closure of the rationals with respect to addition.

Comment: More generally, if $G$ is any abelian group and $H$ is any subgroup, then $aRb \iff a-b\in H$ is an equivalence relation on $G$, using the same proof. (In this question, $G=\Bbb R$ and $H=\Bbb Q$.) This fact is part of the proof that $G/H$ is itself a group.